How to rename a discord voice channel with JDA
This is the part of function I wrote to rename a voice channel in order to show my Minecraft server's online status with voice channel name


    public static void changeName(String online) {


        Guild guild = jda.getGuildById("1122886719126126682");

        VoiceChannel channel = guild.getVoiceChannelById("1147195002603184159");

       channel.getManager().setName(online).queue(

                success -> System.out.println("Successfully renamed to: " + online),
                error -> System.out.println("Failed to rename: " + error.getMessage())

        );
    }

And I got this error (p.s. there are some other printed lines are from other parts of code)

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".


SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation


SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.


SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".


SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.


SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.


[main] INFO JDA - Login Successful!


[JDA MainWS-WriteThread] INFO WebSocketClient - Connected to WebSocket


[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO JDA - Finished Loading!


Server is offline


Exception in thread "main" net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.MissingAccessException: Cannot perform action due to a lack of Permission. Missing permission: VOICE_CONNECT


    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.utils.Checks.checkAccess(Checks.java:303)


    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.managers.channel.ChannelManagerImpl.checkPermissions(ChannelManagerImpl.java:763)


    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.managers.channel.ChannelManagerImpl.<init>(ChannelManagerImpl.java:102)


    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.managers.channel.concrete.VoiceChannelManagerImpl.<init>(VoiceChannelManagerImpl.java:27)


    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.channel.concrete.VoiceChannelImpl.getManager(VoiceChannelImpl.java:167)


    at Main.changeName(Main.java:93)


    at Main.main(Main.java:52
)

I was trying to use this code to rename a voice channel, but it just doesn't work

Your bot is missing permissions, as the error says.

net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.MissingAccessException: Cannot perform action due to a lack of Permission. Missing permission: VOICE_CONNECT
You can change thew bots' permission in the Discord Developer Portal. You should also enable all intents option.

In the error: Cannot perform action due to a lack of Permission. Missing permission: VOICE_CONNECT
Your bot needs permission to see and edit that channel. You can do this in your server settings.
